# How to get strings out of a larger string in Perl

Tags: perl, string

I have several conditions that I have stored in a string under the variable $conditions. The string would look something like this

```
"s(job_name1) or s(job_name2) or s(job_name3) and s(job_name4)"
```

What I would like to do is just get each job name and sore it in a temporary variable. Right now I have the following, but my gut feeling says that that will not work.

```
@temp = split(/(s()\ orand)/, $conditions)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: No this is not homework, I'm just teaching myself perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial:

```
my @names = $conditions =~ /s\(([^)]*)\)/g;
```

This simple solution assumes that the parenthesized text cannot contain more parentheses, and that nothing like escaping is possible.

Edit:  Meant to include this expanded version of the same regex, which might make things a bit clearer:

```
my @names = $conditions =~ m{
    s \(           # match a literal s and opening parenthesis
        (          # then capture in a group
            [^)]*  # a sequence a zero or more
                   # non-right-parenthesis characters
        )
    \)             # followed by a literal closing parenthesis
}gx;               # and return all of the groups that matched
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @jobnames;
while($conditions =~ m/s\(([^)]*)\)/g) {
    push @jobnames, $1;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, although wouldn't I need @jobname to make it an array since there could be more than one job name?

Comment: Ah, I don't think I was clear about what the input looked like since it's not delimited in your question.  Revising.

Comment: my @jobnames = $conditions =~ /s\(([^)]*)\)/g;

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do two things:

- Split the input on either `and` or `or`
- Remove the `s()` bit

Here's one way to do it using `split` and then `map`:

```
@temp = map({/s\(([^)]+)\)/} split(/\s+(?:and|or)\s+/, $conditions));
```

Or slightly more clearly:

```
# Break apart on "and" or "or"
@parts = split(/\s+(?:and|or)\s+/, $conditions);
# Remove the s() bit
@temp = map({/s\(([^)]+)\)/} @parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no nested parentheses.

```
$_ = 's(job_name1) or s(job_name2) or s(job_name3) and s(job_name4)';

my @jobs = /\((.+?)\)/g;

print "@jobs\n";
```